# how to print data from second table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, join, select, subquery

I have main table called **companyNames**, and each row contains the **name of the company,** for eg. TCS, TATAMOTORS, INFY, etc. and also having their tables, like table TCS, table INFY etc, so i'm trying to **print all information** from these table. but it is not printing..

```
 +------------+
| names      |
+------------+
| TCS        |
| INFY       |
| TATAMOTORS |
| TATASTEEL  |
+------------+
Company Name

+------------+---------+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
| date       | high    | low     | open    | close  | volume  | adj_close |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 2015-06-15 | 1260.22 |  1240.5 | 1252.65 | 1252.4 | 2525176 |   1098.59 |
| 2015-06-16 | 1259.65 | 1247.22 |    1250 |   1256 | 1267396 |   1101.74 |
| 2015-06-17 | 1264.57 |  1250.9 |  1260.5 | 1256.9 | 1975720 |   1102.53 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+--------+---------+-----------+  
                               TCS

+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| date       | high    | low     | open   | close  | volume  | adj_close |
+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| 2018-07-15 |  720.22 |   120.5 |   1255 | 1252.4 | 2525176 |   1098.59 |
| 2017-03-11 | 1259.65 | 1247.22 |   12.5 |   1256 |    1267 |   1101.74 |
| 2014-01-14 | 1264.57 |  1250.9 | 1260.5 | 1256.9 | 1975720 |   1102.53 |
+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+ 
                                 INFY
```

after

```
select * from (select names from companyNames) as a;
```

above query is just printing the names of the companies not the information stored in TCS, INFY and other tables.

```
+------------+
| names      |
+------------+
| TCS        |
| INFY       |
| TATAMOTORS |
| TATASTEEL  |
+------------+
```

please help me to print all companies information, also give me suggestions to make the database more effiecient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> help me to print all companies information

Your current schema makes it very hard to achieve what otherwise seems like a simple task. You would need to either hardcode the company names, or use dynamic SQL. The first solution would look like:

```
select c.*, coalesce(t.high, i.high) high, coalesce(t.low, i.low) low, ...
from companies c
left join tcs  t on c.name = 'TCS'
left join infy i on c.name = 'INFY'
left join ...
```

> and also give me suggestions to make the database more effiecient

Do not use separate tables to store the data of different companies. You should have just one table, with a column that refers to the primary key of the `companies` table:

Table companies:

```
company_id    company_name
1             TCS
2             INFY
```

Table stocks:

```
company_id  date          high       low    ...
1           2015-06-15    1260.22    1240.5
1           2015-06-16    1259.65    1247.22
2           2015-06-15     720.22     120.5
2           2015-06-16    1259.65    1247.22
```

Then, you can write your query as a simple join, regardless how actual company names:

```
select c.company_name, s.*
from companies c
inner join stocks s on s.company_id = c.company_id
```

Comment: what to do if my main table cotains, 2k company names, and each company table containg 1.5k of records, will it be efficient, if i use your technique?

Comment: @UbuntuTricks: yes, it will, assuming that you have the proper foreign keys and indexes in place. On the other hand, your original technique would require creating 2000 identical tables, which is a maintenance nightmare and makes it impossible to query across tables.